# Asix usb to network adapter doesn't work (kernel 2.6.32.17)

Tags: usb, embedded-linux

I have got an Edimax USB to Ethernet Adapter which is based on famous ASIX AX88772B chip and I want to make it work with my board which is a ARM based board running an Embedded Linux with Kernel 2.6.32.17

According to Asix documentation this chip is supposed to work in this kernel without problems but it's not working in my case. I have selected the necessary components in kernel as modules (asix, mii, usbnet) and after compiling kernel I have mii.ko, usbnet.ko and asix.ko files. So I copied them to the right place.
After inserting the adapter into hardware I can see that lsusb has recognized a new ASIX USB device with its PID and VID. After this I ran :

> root@dm368-evm:~# modprobe asix
>   usbcore: registered new interface driver asix

and you can see that the modules have been loaded into memory without any errors or problems (apparently modprobe is managing dependencies automatically and I didn't need to insert mii.ko and usbnet.ko manually)

> root@dm368-evm:~# lsmod
>   Module                  Size  Used by
>   asix                   11444  0
>   usbnet                 11657  1 asix
>   mii                     3392  2 asix,usbnet

But I don't see an ethernet interface after running below command

> ifconfig -a

I also don't see any messages in dmesg. I would have expected a message like "eth0 is registered" or something like that based on what I saw in Ubuntu when I plugged in the adapter. I also used this adapter with another ARM hardware which had kernel 3.50 and it worked fine so I have no idea why it's not working.

Once I tried to build the necessary drivers statically into kernel but it didn't make a difference either.

I really need to make this work because the board doesn't have an ethernet connection and I want one to use as debug interface and FTP file transfers.

Comment: Seems like the modules are loaded, but the driver probe is not invoked. Maybe you need to post your kernel's **.config** file, esp.the USB and networking sections. FWIW I've used ASIX adapters with 2.6.28 without issues.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to attach .config file so I upload it here : http://wikisend.com/download/543170/config_USB_ASIX.gz   Please tell me if there was a problem. As you can see in USB Network Adapters section I marked "CONFIG_USB_USBNET" and "CONFIG_USB_NET_AX8817X" as module and also "CONFIG_MII" in MII PHY device drivers section.

Comment: An obvious question - but have you tried other USB devices in the same port? Do they work? Just to eliminate problems with your USB port itself.

Comment: @Alan Au. Yes I plugged in an USB Flash the other day and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Snippets of a `sdiff` of a 2.6.28 configuration (left side) versus your **.config** (right side) follows:

```
#                                                               #
# USB Network Adapters                                          # USB Network Adapters
#                                                               #
# CONFIG_USB_CATC is not set                                    # CONFIG_USB_CATC is not set
# CONFIG_USB_KAWETH is not set                                  # CONFIG_USB_KAWETH is not set
# CONFIG_USB_PEGASUS is not set                                 # CONFIG_USB_PEGASUS is not set
# CONFIG_USB_RTL8150 is not set                                 # CONFIG_USB_RTL8150 is not set
CONFIG_USB_USBNET=y                                           | CONFIG_USB_USBNET=m
CONFIG_USB_NET_AX8817X=y                                      | CONFIG_USB_NET_AX8817X=m
# CONFIG_USB_NET_CDCETHER is not set                          | CONFIG_USB_NET_CDCETHER=m
                                                              > CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_EEM=m
# CONFIG_USB_NET_DM9601 is not set                              # CONFIG_USB_NET_DM9601 is not set
# CONFIG_USB_NET_SMSC95XX is not set                            # CONFIG_USB_NET_SMSC95XX is not set
# CONFIG_USB_NET_GL620A is not set                              # CONFIG_USB_NET_GL620A is not set
# CONFIG_USB_NET_NET1080 is not set                           | CONFIG_USB_NET_NET1080=m
# CONFIG_USB_NET_PLUSB is not set                               # CONFIG_USB_NET_PLUSB is not set
# CONFIG_USB_NET_MCS7830 is not set                             # CONFIG_USB_NET_MCS7830 is not set
# CONFIG_USB_NET_RNDIS_HOST is not set                          # CONFIG_USB_NET_RNDIS_HOST is not set
# CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET is not set                        | CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET=m
# CONFIG_USB_NET_ZAURUS is not set                            | # CONFIG_USB_ALI_M5632 is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_USB_AN2720 is not set
                                                              > CONFIG_USB_BELKIN=y
                                                              > CONFIG_USB_ARMLINUX=y
                                                              > # CONFIG_USB_EPSON2888 is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_USB_KC2190 is not set
                                                              > CONFIG_USB_NET_ZAURUS=m
                                                              > # CONFIG_USB_NET_INT51X1 is not set
# CONFIG_WAN is not set                                         # CONFIG_WAN is not set
# CONFIG_PPP is not set                                       | CONFIG_PPP=m
                                                              > # CONFIG_PPP_MULTILINK is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_PPP_FILTER is not set
                                                              > CONFIG_PPP_ASYNC=m
                                                              > CONFIG_PPP_SYNC_TTY=m
                                                              > CONFIG_PPP_DEFLATE=m
                                                              > # CONFIG_PPP_BSDCOMP is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_PPP_MPPE is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_PPPOE is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_PPPOL2TP is not set
# CONFIG_SLIP is not set                                        # CONFIG_SLIP is not set
# CONFIG_NETCONSOLE is not set                                | CONFIG_SLHC=m
# CONFIG_NETPOLL is not set                                   | CONFIG_NETCONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_NET_POLL_CONTROLLER is not set                       | # CONFIG_NETCONSOLE_DYNAMIC is not set
                                                              > CONFIG_NETPOLL=y
                                                              > CONFIG_NETPOLL_TRAP=y
                                                              > CONFIG_NET_POLL_CONTROLLER=y
# CONFIG_ISDN is not set                                        # CONFIG_ISDN is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_PHONE is not set

...

CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y                                            CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y                                       CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI=y                                    | # CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI is not set
# CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_EHCI is not set                           # CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_EHCI is not set
CONFIG_USB=y                                                    CONFIG_USB=y
CONFIG_USB_DEBUG=y                                            | # CONFIG_USB_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_USB_ANNOUNCE_NEW_DEVICES=y                             | # CONFIG_USB_ANNOUNCE_NEW_DEVICES is not set

#                                                               #
# Miscellaneous USB options                                     # Miscellaneous USB options
#                                                               #
# CONFIG_USB_DEVICEFS is not set                              | CONFIG_USB_DEVICEFS=y
# CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_CLASS is not set                          | CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_CLASS=y
CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MINORS=y                                   | # CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MINORS is not set
# CONFIG_USB_OTG is not set                                     # CONFIG_USB_OTG is not set
# CONFIG_USB_OTG_WHITELIST is not set                           # CONFIG_USB_OTG_WHITELIST is not set
# CONFIG_USB_OTG_BLACKLIST_HUB is not set                       # CONFIG_USB_OTG_BLACKLIST_HUB is not set
# CONFIG_USB_MON is not set                                     # CONFIG_USB_MON is not set
# CONFIG_USB_WUSB is not set                                    # CONFIG_USB_WUSB is not set
# CONFIG_USB_WUSB_CBAF is not set                               # CONFIG_USB_WUSB_CBAF is not set

#                                                               #
# USB Host Controller Drivers                                   # USB Host Controller Drivers
#                                                               #
# CONFIG_USB_C67X00_HCD is not set                              # CONFIG_USB_C67X00_HCD is not set
                                                              > # CONFIG_USB_OXU210HP_HCD is not set
# CONFIG_USB_ISP116X_HCD is not set                             # CONFIG_USB_ISP116X_HCD is not set
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=y                                         | # CONFIG_USB_ISP1760_HCD is not set
# CONFIG_USB_OHCI_BIG_ENDIAN_DESC is not set                  | # CONFIG_USB_ISP1362_HCD is not set
# CONFIG_USB_OHCI_BIG_ENDIAN_MMIO is not set                  <
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_LITTLE_ENDIAN=y                               <
# CONFIG_USB_SL811_HCD is not set                               # CONFIG_USB_SL811_HCD is not set
# CONFIG_USB_R8A66597_HCD is not set                            # CONFIG_USB_R8A66597_HCD is not set
# CONFIG_USB_HWA_HCD is not set                                 # CONFIG_USB_HWA_HCD is not set
# CONFIG_USB_MUSB_HDRC is not set                             | CONFIG_USB_MUSB_HDRC=y
                                                              > CONFIG_USB_MUSB_SOC=y
                                                              >
```

You should investigate if your SoC has support for CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI and CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD

I suggest you use `make menuconfig` to enable

```
Drivers
    USB support  
        Support for Host-side USB  
            USB verbose debug messages
            USB announce new devices
```

Comment: Thank you. Well I have enabled "USB verbose debug messages" and "USB announce new devices" options but it didn't help that much. The real problem is that I couldn't find CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI and CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD under the current config. I guess those are not available for my SoC like you'd expected. I searched for CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI in menuconfig and turns out it is there but I guess it depends on different architectures and I can't access those in current architecture which is TI Davinci. OR maybe I'm missing something or I'm doing it wrong. I don't know. Is there anyway around?

Comment: Ok, forget it. Seems like I can't get it to work. There must be some serious problems with the SoC itself. Anyway I decided to make a ethernet interface using usb connection (USB Ethernet Gadget CDC) and it worked quite well and now I have an ethernet interface named usb0. Sorry to bother you guys.